# Alpine JS Toggle Input Values

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have a button that I want to toggle the value on a html input element from 0 to 1 and vice versa but I can't figure out how to do it with Alpine JS.

```
// input will be 0 or 1
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="status" x-ref="status">

// Toggles the status between 1 and 0 
<button type="button" 
x-data="{ on: false }" :class="{ 'bg-gray-200': !on, 'bg-primary-600': on }" 
@click="$refs.status.value = 1"
>Toggle Status</button>
```

I was able to get the code above to change the input value to 1 but can't figure out how to get it to toggle it back and forth. Any ideas would mean a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

```html
<div x-data="{ status: false }">

    <form>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="status" x-model.number="status">


        <span x-text="status"></span>
        
        <button type="button" x-on:click="status = !status">
            Toggle Status
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The global `status` is held at the `div` element. The status is outputted inside a `span` using [`x-text`](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-text).

The hidden `input` is bound to the `status` using [`x-model`](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-model) and transforming the `boolean` value to a number using the `.number` modifier.

### Update

For whatever reasons this does not work anymore, I created a new sample here: https://codepen.io/codedge/pen/wvgNqee

It just defines two `x-data` values, one for the boolean value and one for the integer one.

```html
<div x-data="{ status: false, num: 0 }">

    <form>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="num">


        <span x-text="num"></span>
        
        <button type="button" x-on:click="status = !status; num = (status == true ? 1 : 0)">
            Toggle Status
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Value is changed to "true" or "false" being strings. I need "0" and "1". Laravel validation treats "0" and "1" (even though they're strings) as boolean. But "true" and "false" as strings where "false" is seen as true because it's not an empty string. The .number modifier doesn't have effect.